# Python 3.9 [64-bit] - unable to readback the correct VOLT? from the DC Power Supply in the first RUN

Tags: python, pyvisa

My issue is the following:

I program using PYCharm editor a certain voltage on my DC Power Supply and hit the RUN button.
The read back actual actual voltage is available on my DC Voltmeter only, However on PyCharm **Console** it display the previous voltage read back voltage or nothing!.
I need to hit the RUN button the second time in order to read back on the PYCharm Console.

I wish to hit the RUN button [only once] and read back the actual voltage on both the DVM and the PYCharm Console in real time.

Here is my python codes:

import pyvisa
import time

```
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources())
PSU = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x5345::0x1235::2017052::INSTR')

PSU.write_termination = '\n'
print(PSU.query("*IDN?"))

    PSU.write('*RST')
    PSU.write('*CLS')

    PSU.write('OUTPUT ON')
    PSU.write('VOLT 7.4')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    PSU.write('VOLT?')
```

Many Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: The only line that prints anything from the instrument is *before* the line that sets the voltage, so it should be obvious that it's not going to print the new voltage.  Perhaps that 'VOLT?' command should be a `.query()` instead of of a `.write()`, and you could print its result?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyvisa
import time

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources())
PSU = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x5345::0x1235::2017052::INSTR')

PSU.write_termination = '\n'
print(PSU.query("*IDN?"))

PSU.write('*RST')
PSU.write('*CLS')

time.sleep(0.5)
PSU.write('OUTPUT ON')
PSU.write('VOLT 2.9')
print(PSU.query("VOLT?"))
```

Comment: PyCharm Python Console:
I need some assiatance to write python codes to do the following:
1. I require to receive a user input [integer] to change voltage in the DC Power Supply.
2. Example the code to change the DC Voltage to 3.3 Volts is: PSU.write('VOLT 3.3').
3. These changes must take place at run time.
Thanks & Best Regards